# Pop-ups in Chrome

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, google-chrome

Hi I'm using Chrome in a MBP and anytime that I click anywhere on the page I`m browsing, a pop-up opens and I cannot stop it. I have already tried with configuration of Chrome but it's useless.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.adwaremedic.com and download and install the Adware Medic software to remove the adware. It will search for the specific adware that usually gets installed from questionable websites, i.e. a website to stream a movie.

Once ran, the program will show you the file locations of the documents it is removing.

Otherwise, go to preferences- extensions in Google Chrome and remove anything you did not install. However, this will not remove any launchagents or launchdaemons or frameworks installed by the initial installation of the adware.